# How can i access Textview inside View?

Tags: android, view

Am creating icons on gridview dynamically, I want to access the clicked item on the grid view.

Onclick event displays the elements as below,

[image]

I need to get the textview's text using code or I want to access the value of mTransformed. how can I achieve it?

```
public void onClick(View v) {           
   ArrayList<View> result = new ArrayList<View>();
   ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) v;
    for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {

        View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(1);
        int id = child.getId();
   }
}
```

Comment: maybe show where you set the onlclicklistener so it is clear what the view recieved in onClick(View v) represents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are are creating the icons dynamically just set the id as 
view.setId(1);
Its is not neccessary to get id's with the number
just call
view.getId();
this will automatocally get the id of the particular view but one should be carefull in giving id's because if two different views have the same id's like view1.setId(1); and view2.setId(1); then you will get an error 
If you are creating the views dynamically then give setId(i); and run i in a loop

Comment: I have set the id as you said, but when i use getid it returns as -1

Answer (score 1):

onClick returns the view you clicked upon. So if you click on a TextView you can simple do:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
     int id = v.getId();
     if (id == R.id.idoftextview) {
         String text = ((TextView)v).getText().toString();
     }
 }
```

Comment: The thing is I dont know the id of textview because icons and textviews are dynamically created. And getID rturns -1 always.

Comment: you can use setId while you create your textview.View (the parent class for TextView) has setId(int). This way you could fix the -1 issue

Comment: Ya thats how it is, there are 100 of icons so how do you find which one is clicked?

Comment: 100 ? Are you sure you do not want to use something like ListView ? you can create a Different instance of View.OnClickListener for each icon

Comment: Am using library called pageddragdroppedgrid , i add the icons dynamically to the gridview, this onclick is provided by the library